# Как применить эффект тени QGraphicsDropShadowEffect к QGraphicsItem?

Tags: qt5, qt, c++

Хочу добавлять Items в QGraphicsScene и хочу, чтобы они отбрасывали тень. Я использую следующий код, но безуспешно:

```
scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);

QGraphicsDropShadowEffect * effect = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect();
effect->setBlurRadius(50);

QGraphicsRectItem * item = new QGraphicsRectItem(100,100,50,50);
item->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::cyan));
item->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
scene->addItem(item);
```

Однако если применить этот же эффект к graphicsView, работает отлично

```
  ui->graphicsView->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
```

В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужен прокси. Та же проблема была, вот аноним когда-то помог решить:

https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/development/10631940?lastmod=1404293866953#comment-10632350